# Why are there different neurotransmitters in central nervous system?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, evolution, neuro-transmitters

If an effect of binding the neurotransmitter depends on the receptor type, not the neurotransmitter itself, then why don't we have just one neurotransmitter and many different receptors?

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont is likely relevant, though there are also places where multiple neurotransmitters are used in close proximity where they wouldn't be interchangeable.

Comment: The question "why do we have multiple neurotransmitters/receptors" is indeed interesting imo, but how well a ligand binds to a receptor depends on its molecular geometry. Some neurotransmitters might bind fairly well to multiple receptors, but globally to each receptor its neurotransmitter.